# Dendropy interpop module python

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to work with the python Dendropy library and include some PAUP commands inside my code.

I'm using the tutorial mentioned in the [python library](http://packages.python.org/DendroPy/tutorial/paup.html), but it's giving me an error.

So what I'm doing is I'm trying to estimate a tree from a distance matrix:

***Distance matrix A (Numpy array)***

```
[[ 0  2  7  8 16 17]
 [ 2  0  5  6 17 16]
 [ 7  5  0  9 15 13]
 [ 8  6  9  0 18 16]
 [16 17 15 18  0  5]
 [17 16 13 16  5  0]]

import dendropy
from dendropy.interpop import paup     

#A is a distance matrix like this    

tree = paup.estimate_tree(A, 'nj')
```

The error I'm getting is: `ImportError: No module named interpop`

I have PAUP installed on my machine and the tutorial does not talk about installing any additional modules.

Any help would be appreciated.

***EDIT***
does this work with NUMPY arrays ?? because it seems to give an error with numpy arrays.. and how to solve this problem ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `from dendropy.interop import paup` (minus the `p` in `interpop`). I mis-typed it twice writing this answer, so if that is the cause of the error then it is an understandable one :)

Comment: ok, this was it :) but i will update the question and include 1 more question. please have a look

Comment: @ifreak Good to hear. What is the error you are getting with the arrays? My numpy experience is very limited/non-existent, so it may be better suited to another question if it involves a more educated answer :)

Comment: i would open a new question then about it.. since a totaly different error

Comment: @ifreak Ha, makes sense - at least we got the first part figured out.